# Optimize shell script (bash) to impove performance

Tags: python, linux, perl, bash, shell

I have a bash script which I use to process a text file:

```
#/bin/bash

dos2unix sourcefile.txt

cat sourcefile.txt | grep -v '\/' | grep -v '\-\-' | grep -v '#' | grep '[A-Za-z]\*' > modified_sourcefile.txt

mv modified_sourcefile.txt sourcefile.txt
#
# Read the sourcefile file one line by line and iterate...
#

while read line
do

 echo $line | grep -v '\/' | grep -v '\-\-' | grep -v '#'
 if [ $? -eq 0 ]
 then

   # echo "Current Line is " $line ";"
    char1=`echo ${line:0:1}`
   # echo "1st char is " $char1

  if [ -n "$char1" ]
   # if a blank-line, neglect the line.
    then
        # echo "test passed"
        var1=`echo $line | cut -d '*' -f 1`
    var2=`echo $line | cut -d '*' -f 1`
    var3=`echo $line | cut -d - -f 1`
        var4=`echo $line | cut -d '*' -f 1`
        var5=`echo $line | cut -d '*' -f 2`
        var6=`echo $line | cut -d - -f 1`
        var7=`echo $line | cut -d '*' -f 3 `


        table1sql="INSERT IGNORE INTO table1 (id,name,active_yesno,category,description,
           last_modified_by,last_modified_date_time) SELECT ifnull(MAX(id),0)+1,'$var1',1,
           '$var2','$var3','admin',NOW() FROM table1;"

    echo $table1sql >> result.txt


    privsql="INSERT IGNORE INTO table2 (id,name,description,active_yesno,group_code,
             last_modified_by,last_modified_date_time) SELECT ifnull(MAX(id),0)+1,'$var1',
         '$var3',1,'$var2','admin',NOW() FROM table2;"

    echo $privsql >> result.txt     


    table1privmapsql="INSERT IGNORE INTO table1_table2_map (id,table1_id,table2_id,
                  last_modified_by,last_modified_date_time) SELECT ifnull(MAX(id),0)+1,
                  (select id from table1 where name='$var1'),(select id from table2 where name='$var1'),'admin',NOW() FROM table1_table2_map;"
    echo $table1privmapsql >> result.txt

        privgroupsql="INSERT IGNORE INTO table2_group (id,name,category,active_yesno,last_modified_by,
                      last_modified_date_time) SELECT ifnull(MAX(id),0)+1,'tablegrp','$pgpcode',1,'admin',NOW() FROM table2_group;"

        echo $privgroupsql >> result.txt


    privprivgrpsql="INSERT IGNORE INTO table2_table2group_map (id,table2_id,table2_group_id,
                        last_modified_by,last_modified_date_time) SELECT ifnull(MAX(id),0)+1,
                        (select id from table2 where name='$var1'),(select id from table2_group where name='tablegrp'),'admin',NOW() FROM table2_table2group_map;"
        echo $privprivgrpsql >> result.txt              

    rolesql="INSERT IGNORE INTO role (id,name,active_yesno,security_domain_id,last_modified_by,last_modified_date_time) 
                 SELECT (select ifnull(MAX(id),0)+1 from role),'$rolename',1, sd.id ,'admin',NOW() 
                 FROM security_domain sd WHERE sd.name = 'General';"

        echo $rolesql >> result.txt

    fi                  
 fi                        
done < "sourcefile.txt"
```

The thing is sourcefile.txt has over 11000 lines. So it takes about 25 min to complete :-( .

Is there a better way of doing it?

contents of sourcefile.txt:

```
AAA-something*LOCATION-some_where*ABC
```

Answer (score 5):

To make this script faster you must minimize calls to external commands and use bash where is possible.

1. read [this article](http://partmaps.org/era/unix/award.html) to know what is useless use of commands.
2. read [this article](http://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/string-manipulation.html) to know how to use bash to manipulate strings.
3. replace repeating values(var1, var2, var4) assignment to single value.

While optimizing `cut` you can replace

```
var1=`echo $line | cut -d '*' -f 1`
```

to

```
var1="${line%%\**}"
```

And

```
var5=`echo $line | cut -d '*' -f 2`
```

to

```
var5="${line%\**}"
var5="${var5##*\*}"
```

Maybe it not so human-readable, but works much faster than cut.

Also

```
 echo $line | grep -v '\/' | grep -v '\-\-' | grep -v '#'
```

can be replaced to something like that:

```
 if [[ "$line" =~ ([/#]|--) ]]; then :; else 
    # all code inside "if [ $? -eq 0 ]"
 fi
```

Comment: Those string operations are really cool . It did bring the time down.

Comment: it should be pointed out that the other extreme is viable option, minimize the use of bash and maximize the use of piped external commands

Answer (score 4):

shell scripts are inherently slow, especially when they use a lot of external commands like yours. Biggest reason for this is because spawning external process is rather slow, and you do it a lot of times.

If you are *really* after high performance processing of your data, you should write Perl or Python script which would do what you need without ever spawning any external process: no `dos2unix`, no `grep`, no `cut` or anything like that.

Perl (and Python) are also perfectly capable of talking directly to database and inserting data, also without using external commands.

If you do it right, I predict that processing performance using Perl will be at least 100x faster than you have now.

If you are ok with Perl, you can start with something like this and adjust to your liking:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl -w

use strict;
use warnings;

open FILE, "sourcefile.txt" or die $!;
open RESULT, ">>result.txt" or die $!;
while (my $line = <FILE>) {
    # ignore lines with /, -- or #: 
    next if $line =~ m{/|--|#};
    my ($var1, $var2, $var3, $var4, $var5) =
        ($line =~ /^(\w+)-(\w+)\*(\w+)-(\w+)\*(\w+)/);
    # ignore line if regex did not match:
    next unless $var1 and $var2 and $var3 and $var4 and $var5;
    print RESULT "some sql stmt. using $var1, $var2, etc";
    print RESULT "some other sql using $var1, $var2, etc";
    # ...
}
close RESULT;
close FILE;
```

Comment: I think ur right . did some reading ,seems like pearl is the way to go. However I'am not familiar with pearl. nee to read more i think .

Comment: Thanks mvp 
Tried the script this does make the whole thing super fast.. abt 1 min
I am going to fool around with shell scripting a little more see if can bring down the time to atleast < 5 min

Comment: That's why I just don't bother with shell scripts, even simple ones - not worth the effort. Much easier to write Perl from get go. Now imagine how much time you could save if you talk to database directly from Perl.

Answer (score 1):

Before optimizing, profile! Learn how to use the [time](http://linux.die.net/man/1/time) command. Find out which part of your script takes the most time, and put your effort there.

Having said that, I would think that having multiple passes of `grep` will slow things down a bit.

This:

```
cat sourcefile.txt | grep -v '\/' | grep -v '\-\-' | grep -v '#' | grep '[A-Za-z]\*'
```

can be replaced by this:

```
grep '[A-Za-z]\*' sourcefile.txt | grep -v -e '\/' -e '\-\-' -e '#'
```

Comment: I think this won't improve things, not a single bit. Real problem here is calling `cut` a lot of times

Comment: I actually did use the time command and found out that a lot of time is spend for variable substitution inside the loop. I also tried appending the strings to a single variable and at the end of the loop dump it result.txt . this approach did save some 2 min but still not enough.

Comment: @mvp That's not true, every unnecessary fork is a problem and this does improve things a lot (inside the loop anyway). `$ time for i in {1..100}; do echo "$i" | grep -v -e '\/' -e '\-\-' -e '#' >/dev/null; done` vs. `$ time for i in {1..100}; do echo "$i" | grep -v '\/' | grep -v '\-\-' | grep -v '#' >/dev/null; done` yields an improvement of more than 50% on my box, which translates to 13 minutes - not bad in my book. Since the input strings will be longer, the gain should be even bigger in a real scenario. But I do agree, `perl` is the better tool for this job.